# Problem with WEBP and LENSFUN when installing 'darktable' from source using cmake

Tags: cmake, webp

I'm trying to install darktable from source. To this end,
I downloaded darktable-2.4.4.tar.xz from [here](https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/releases/tag/release-2.4.4). After unpacking I try to build it with

```
sudo ./build.sh
```

I get the following errors:

```
(...)
-- Checking for one of the modules 'libsoup-2.2;libsoup2'
-- Could NOT find WEBP (missing: WEBP_LIBRARY WEBP_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "0.3.0")
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
Could NOT find LENSFUN (missing: LENSFUN_LIBRARY LENSFUN_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
cmake/modules/FindLensFun.cmake:37 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
src/CMakeLists.txt:286 (find_package)
```

However, both WEBP and LENSFUN are installed.

```
sudo apt-get install webp

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
webp is already the newest version (0.6.1-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

LENSFUN was installed from source.

It's worth mentioning build.sh uses cmake.

What can I do to solve these problems?

Comment: My crystal ball says: "Install appropriate -dev packages".

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: He means that "pure" `webp` package contains only *libraries* but not *headers* files, which are needed for **build** a project against webp library. Header files for libraries are usually contained in additional, "development", packages, which names end with "-dev" or "-devel". E.g. on Fedora the webp development package is named [libwebp-devel](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/libwebp-devel).

Comment: ok, I tried sufo apt-get install webp-dev and webp-devel and I got: E: Unable to locate package webp-dev and E: Unable to locate package webp-devel.